# iOS 9 Spotlight Search with CoreSpotlight: cannot replace thumbnail

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9, corespotlight

I am working on a proof of concept about Spotlight Search using a "semi-static" CoreSpotlight db created and replaced on-the-fly when needed.

Here's the code I use for wiping and re-creating the whole stuff (assuming `items` is a NSArray of `CSSearchableItem`s):

```
[[CSSearchableIndex defaultSearchableIndex] deleteAllSearchableItemsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError * __nullable error){
    if (!error) {
        [[CSSearchableIndex defaultSearchableIndex] indexSearchableItems:items completionHandler:nil];
    }
}];
```

Almost everything works fine apart from the fact that, if in the process of wiping and rebuilding I try to recreate an item with the same `uniqueIdentifier` but different `thumbnailData` (or even no thumbnail at all), it seems to "remember" the thumbnail it was initially created with, and does not acquire the new one.

What's even more curious is that I can replace `title`, `contentDescription` and `keywords`.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated...

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior.  It does seem like an iOS bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the bug in the iOS 9, **other attributes are updating while thumbnail attribute is not updating**. You have to wait for new iOS version may it be fixed in it.